# Как построчно ввести целые числа ?(с++)

Tags: c++, строки, ввод

На вход даются целые числа. На каждой строке находится какое-то количество этих целых чисел (может и вообще их не быть). Мне нужно переместить целые числа в i-й строке в массив с номером i. Пример:

4       //количество строк
2 3     //числа которые должны попасть в 1 массив
3       //число которое должно попасть во 2 массив
        //3-й массив должен остаться пустым
2      //в 4-й массив соответственно должно попасть число на 4 строчке

Можно ли считать данные без использования string и char[] и если да, то как?

Comment: Если проблема в том как из `char*` или `string` получить `int`, то можно воспользоваться `int atoi (const char * str)` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

А сразу в `int` считать не получиться

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Поскольку у вас количество чисел в строке не фиксировано, вам нужно считывать строки целиком, а затем их обрабатывать. Например, что-то типа (набросок, не более того)

```
in >> N;
for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
{
    getline(in,s);
    istringstream is(s);
    while(is >> n) { /* Вносим n в i-й массив */ };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да. Например при помощи [`std::istream::peek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) вы можете подсмотреть какой следующий символ в потоке не извлекая его, и если там конец строки, то считать что эта строка закончилась и переходить к следующей. Но такой подход создает дополнительные трудности. Если вы избегайте строк потому что не знакомы с ними, то лучше познакомьтесь, если это такое задание, то у вас очень коварный учебник/преподаватель/интервьюер.

Решение без строк, но с ошибками(если пользователь введет пробелы в конце строки):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int readInt(){
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}

bool isEndOfLine(){    
    int next = std::cin.peek();
    return next == '\n' || next == EOF;
}

void skipLine(){
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}


int main(){
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    skipLine();

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        while(!isEndOfLine()){
            data[i].push_back(readInt());
        }

        skipLine();
    }

    //...
}
```

http://cpp.sh/7fhsy

Для хранения данных использовал вектора, потому что с ними проще управляться чем с массивами, но на суть решения это не повлияло.